# Flutter I can't save object with SharedPreference

Tags: flutter, dart

I know there are questions like this, but I want to ask my question through the code I wrote.
I'm creating an object and passing it into a list and I give key and list as parameters and saving that list as setStringList but it doesn't saving and I don't get any errors.

**SharedPreference class :**

```dart
class SharedPrefs {
  int counter = 0;

  save(String key, list) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (!prefs.containsKey('counter')) {
      prefs.setInt('counter', counter); // set the counter
    } else {
      counter = prefs.getInt('counter')!;
    }

    if (!prefs.containsKey(key + counter.toString())) {
      prefs.setStringList(key + counter.toString(), list);

      prefs.setInt('counter', counter + 1);
    }
  }

  Future<List<NotePages>> loadAllPages() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    List<NotePages> pages = [];

    final keys = prefs.getKeys();
    var shared;

    for (String key in keys) {
      shared = prefs.getStringList(key);

      if (shared[0] == 'page') {
        NotePages page = NotePages(
            type: shared[0], pageName: shared[1], createdTime: shared[2]);

        pages.add(page);
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }

    return pages;
  }

  getValue(key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.get(key);
  }
}
```

**This is how I'm trying to save:**

```
 child: TextButton(
         onPressed: () {
            NotePages page = NotePages(
            type: 'page',
            pageName: myController.text,
            createdTime: DateTime.now());

            List<String> pageList = [
            page.type,
            page.pageName,
            page.createdTime.toIso8601String()
             ];
           prefs.save('page', pageList);

            Navigator.pop(context);
           }
```

**And this is how I'm trying to load:**

```
SharedPrefs prefs = SharedPrefs();

  getPages() async {
    notePages = await prefs.loadAllPages();
    
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getPages();

    for (var i = 0; i < notePages.length; i++) {
      dropDownItemValue.add(notePages[i].pageName);
    }
    dropDownItemValue.add('');
    dropDownItemValue.add('Add Page');
    print(dropDownItemValue);
    // selected value must be contain at dropDownItemValue
    selectedValue = dropDownItemValue[0];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getPages()` function's return type is `Future<void>`.
The Code that adding `dropDownItemValue` will run before initializing the `notePages`.
So you need to await the function like below.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getPages().then((_) {
    for (var i = 0; i < notePages.length; i++) {
      dropDownItemValue.add(notePages[i].pageName);
    }
    dropDownItemValue.add('');
    dropDownItemValue.add('Add Page');
    print(dropDownItemValue);
    // selected value must be contain at dropDownItemValue
    selectedValue = dropDownItemValue[0];
  });
}
```

#### EDIT

I think using the getStringList() with a key that is not of type List caused a problem when getting the List. How about adding an if-branch like below?

```dart
Future<List<NotePages>> loadAllPages() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  List<NotePages> pages = [];

  final keys = prefs.getKeys();
  var shared;

  for (String key in keys) {
    if (key == 'counter') continue; // <--- This
    shared = prefs.getStringList(key);

    if (shared[0] == 'page') {
      NotePages page = NotePages(
          type: shared[0], pageName: shared[1], createdTime: shared[2]);

      pages.add(page);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  return pages;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, this time nothing was added to the dropdownList. And the main problem is that I am not able to save the data. unfortunately i still haven't figured it out.

Comment: @cançağlarkırıcı please check the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me, but I noticed something else. When I write Print("asdf") inside the load or save functions, I cannot see that print in the DebugConsole. I can see that those functions are called, but the prints are not visible, I guess, actually the code is not even called at all. so I changed the code and made json encode/decode, saved it to SharedPreference and converted it as a map. and the code still didn't work I used Then() again as you first said, but again I'm not sure if the code was called I'm just learning flutter I think Im making mistakes with asynchronous